# How to put a value in flash when testing an action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I'm trying to test an action that needs a value stored in flash.

```
def my_action
  if flash[:something].nil?
    redirect_to root_path if flash[:something]
    return
  end

  # Do some other stuff
end
```

In my test I do something like:

```
before(:each) do
  flash[:something] = "bob"
end

it "should do whatever I had commented out above" do
  get :my_action
  # Assert something
end
```

The problem I'm running into is that flash has no values inside of my_action.  I'm guessing this is because no request actually happens.

Is there a way to set flash up for a test like this?

Comment: have you tried it with `flash.now[:something]` ?

Comment: Looking at the code in `my_action`, it seems like `flash[:something]` is never set, because the `redirect_to root_path` happens only if `flash[:something]` is not nil, but the redirect is inside an if block thats true only if `flash[:something]`, so the problem might just be that your action never really sets `flash[:something]` to a non-nil value. Maybe you should first confirm that with `console.log`?

Comment: So in normal use another action somewhere else sets flash[:something] to a value and redirects to my_action.  my_action doesn't ever set flash[:something], it just expects it to have already been set.  I was trying to do that by setting it in the test itself.

Comment: just tried flash.now[:something] = "bob" in my before_each but the results are the same :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that using the flash hash the way you do means it only becomes avaialble for the next request. In order to set the flash hash to a value for your test, you could write something like this:

```
def test_something_keeps_flash
  @request.flash[:something] = 'bar'
  xhr :get, :my_action
  assert_response :success
  // Assert page contents here
end
```

This ensures that you can check the logic of your action. Because it will now set the flash hash properly, enter your **my_action** and perform the check on the flash hash.

Comment: I ended up doing something entirely different with my code so this wasn't necessary but I did verify that I could use xhr and probably get it to work.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem, and none of this is working for me. Did this change in a recent version of rspec?

Comment: For Rails 3.2.12, rSpec 2.13.1, this works: flash[:key] = value; flash.stub! :sweep; post :create, params, flash: flash

Answer (score 11):

I had to solve a similar issue;
I had a controller action that redirected to one of two paths at completion depending of the value of a hash entry.
The spec test that I found worked, for your example above, was:

```
it "should do whatever I had commented out above" do
  get :my_action, action_params_hash, @current_session, {:something=>true}
  # Assert something
end
```

@current_session is a hash with session specific stuf; I'm using authlogic.
I found about using the fourth argument of get for the flash in [[A Guide to Testing Rails Applications[1]](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html)). I found that the same approach also works for delete; and I presume all others.

Comment: this was the only answer I got to work under rails 3.0.20 and rspec 2.99

Comment: Thank you, this works. From the linked article:

Calling the :view action, passing an id of 12 as the params, this time with no session, but with a flash message.

`get(:view, {'id' => '12'}, nil, {'message' => 'booya!'})`

Answer (score 10):

the following worked for me with RoR 4.1:

```
flash_hash = ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash.new
flash_hash[:error] = 'an error'
session['flash'] = flash_hash.to_session_value

get :my_action
```