# Rspec - how do I call a GET and send flash message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I know it is strange to be passing this data via flash, but there's some (likely flawed) logic for why it's happening and rather than rewire it right now, I wanted to try to get this test working. The test keeps returning the `:error` template when it should return the `:success` based on a legit `flash[:thing_id]` (the actual app behavior works).

**From Controller:**

```
def post_multiple_new
  @thing = Thing.find_by_id(flash[:thing_id].to_i)
  unless @thing
    render :error
  else
    render :success
  end
end
```

**From Spec:**

```
context 'when valid id' do
  let(:thing) { create(:thing) }
  let(:flash) { {thing_id: thing.id.to_s} }
  it 'renders correctly' do
    get :post_multiple_new
    expect(response).to render_template(:success)
  end
end
```

Comment: I highly recommend installing the `byebug` gem in order to ensure that the variable in your controller is what it should be. https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug

Comment: Test in your spec if "thing" has been created and what id is passed to thing_id

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793414/how-to-put-a-value-in-flash-when-testing-an-action

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Kristján - the bottom answer in your [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793414/how-to-put-a-value-in-flash-when-testing-an-action) worked.

`context 'when valid game id' do
  let!(:thing) { create(:thing) }
  it 'renders correctly' do
    flash_hash = ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash.new
    flash_hash[:thing_id] = thing.id
    session['flash'] = flash_hash.to_session_value
    get :post_multiple_new
    expect(response).to render_template(:success)
  end
end`